# Multiplying two cells in a table together

Tags: javascript

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSCLC/3/

I have a script (below) that adds a row to a table.

I am wanting to add two cells together to get a total

```
Item Price * Item Weight = Line Total 

if (field.value.length != 0) {
    var upc=document.getElementById("UPC").value;
    var weight=document.getElementById("weight").value +"lbs";
    var table=document.getElementById("ScannedItems");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6=row.insertCell(5);
    cell1.innerHTML=upc;
    cell2.innerHTML="Example Description";
    cell3.innerHTML="$3.00";
    cell4.innerHTML=weight;
    var total=cell3.innterHTML*cell4.innerHTML;
    cell5.innerHTML="$" +total;
    cell6.innerHTML="<a><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' style='padding-right:15px;'></span></a><span>&nbsp;</span><a><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></a>";
    field.value ='';
}
```

I have tried making a new variable after the two cells and before the new cell but all I get is `$Nan` in the table.

The specific lines I am messing with is:

```
cell3.innerHTML="$3.00";
cell4.innerHTML=weight;
var total=cell3.innterHTML*cell4.innerHTML;
cell5.innerHTML="$" +total;
```

Comment: a) `innerHTML` returns a string b) you can't multiply things like dollars and weights, only integers/floats, so you need to multiply before appending dollar sign and so on.

Comment: I just tried changing `innterHTML` to `value` with the same results

Comment: `value` returns string as well, convert it into a number.

Comment: And how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @JakubMichálek Would you please put that as an answer and not a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to parse integers out of user input. Next, you need to multiply. And THEN append any units:

```
var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value);
var price = 3;
var total = weight * price;

//

cell3.innerHTML = "$" + price.toFixed(2);
cell4.innerHTML = weight + "lbs";
cell5.innerHTML = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
```

---

**Edit based on comments**

Accessing `data-attributes` is done via `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.

```
cell5.setAttribute('data-total', total); // caches the total into data

var total = cell5.getAttribute('data-total'); // reads the value
```

Comment: What about adding all the line total together to achieve a sub total?

Comment: You could either store the numeric values using `data-attributes` on the `td` or `substr` and `parseInt` it back everytime from `innerHTML`.

Comment: I tried `cell5.data-total = total;` and it stopped the loading of the rest of the script.

Comment: I'll put it in the answer in a minute.

Comment: I need a "running" sub total meaning if I add another item to the table, the subtotal increases and vice versa for deleting an item.

Comment: Well, data-attributes might a little impractical for live counting (JS variable would be the easier choice) but adding this behaviour is simple: when new row is added, iterate over existing rows, read the data and add them together; when it's removed, substract the value of removed row.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: So, where is the problem? I'm not gonna write it all, but I'll gladly help if there is something specific you have trouble with.

Comment: I'm not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I am just pointing the errors, You can debug

```
    var upc=document.getElementById("UPC").value;
    var weight=document.getElementById("weight").value +"lbs"; // here appending lbs to weight
    var table=document.getElementById("ScannedItems");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6=row.insertCell(5);
    cell1.innerHTML=upc;
    cell2.innerHTML="Example Description";
    cell3.innerHTML="$3.00"; // value having $, so maths operation won't work
    cell4.innerHTML=weight; // value having lbs, so maths operation won't work 
    var total=cell3.innterHTML*cell4.innerHTML; // Is not an integer
```

Instead of above you can try something like this

```
   var weight=document.getElementById("weight").value;
   var table=document.getElementById("ScannedItems");
   var row=table.insertRow(-1);
   var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
   var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
   var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
   var cell6=row.insertCell(5);
   cell1.innerHTML=upc;
   cell2.innerHTML="Example Description";
   cell3.innerHTML="$3.00";
   cell4.innerHTML=weight+"lbs";
   var total=3*weight;
```